# Node Application sends emails using AWS SES works fine in local but not sending email in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, email, lambda, amazon-ses

> Node application based on AWS SES works good in localhost but not sending emails in aws lambda

The application is developed using Node v18.12.1. Used AWS SES service in sandbox with both sender and receiver emails registered & verified in SES. I've deployed the application in AWS Lambda using serverless. The application works as expected and sends emails when it runs locally but not sending any emails from lambda.

The following code.

```
const e = require('express');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const app = e();


aws.config.update({ region: 'ap-northeast-1' });


app.post('/sendmail',async(req,res)=>{
  try{
     let mailResponse = await sendMail(req.body);
     res.status(200).json({mailStatus: mailResponse})
  }
  catch(err){
   res.send(error);
  }
})
module.exports.apex =  ServerlessHttp(app);
```

The function used to send email is as follows

```
const sendMail = async (params) => {

        const { toAddress, baseUrl, dealId, applicantName, dealType, appLogo } = params;
        const url = `${baseUrl}/personalInfo/${dealId}`;
        const jsonParameters = {
            "user": applicantName,
            "image":appLogo,
            "dealType":dealType,
            "link":url
        }
        const jsonPayload = JSON.stringify(jsonParameters);

        var emailParams = {
            Destination: { 
              ToAddresses: [
                toAddress,

              ]
            },
            Source: "info_some_random_app@gmail.com", 
            Template: 'MyTemplate', 
            TemplateData: jsonPayload, 

          };
        try {

                var sendPromise = new aws.SES({apiVersion: '2010-12-01'}).sendTemplatedEmail(emailParams).promise();
                sendPromise.then(res=>{
                    return res;
                }).catch(err=>{
                    throw err;
                })

        } catch (error) {
            throw e;
        }
    };
```

- Tried registering the sender email and receiver email in the SES console and verified them.

used cloud watch for the error logging

The coludwatch logs for aws lambda

```
INIT_START Runtime Version: nodejs:14.v28   Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-1::runtime:be4a32da6aeaa90583d476cb548ced79ae2c9aa7b14a45129198bbd13ea5822d
2023-02-07T07:20:53.728Z    undefined   INFO    App is running
START RequestId: f95d3ced-0e85-4454-88f8-209f00bb1822 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: f95d3ced-0e85-4454-88f8-209f00bb1822
REPORT RequestId: f95d3ced-0e85-4454-88f8-209f00bb1822  Duration: 84.24 ms  Billed Duration: 85 ms  Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 117 MB Init Duration: 1338.26 ms
```